# React LinkedIn Login OAuth2.0

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0

I want to implement an OAuth in my react-app. To do that, I added "npm i react-linkedin-login-oauth2" from npmjs.com.

Below is the code I used from the documentation:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

````
import linkedin from 'react-linkedin-login-oauth2';

function LinkedInPage() {
  const { linkedInLogin } = useLinkedIn({
    clientId: '86vhj2q7ukf83q',
    redirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/linkedin`, // for Next.js, you can use `${typeof window === 'object' && window.location.origin}/linkedin`
    onSuccess: (code) => {
      console.log(code); //returns AccessCode
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    },
  });

  return (
    <img
      onClick={linkedInLogin}
      src={linkedin}
      alt="Sign in with Linked In"
      style={{ maxWidth: '180px', cursor: 'pointer' }}
    />
  );
} ```

Apparently, this solution returns an Access Token yet I would like to view a person's profileName, Surname and profilePicture.
````

Comment: did you find any way?

Comment: Not yet, @IbadUrRehman